# Is possible to generate Trend Line in Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

Is it possible with **apache POI** to create **trend line** on chart, or have I to calculate points where trend line function is? I was searching any informations about that, but I can't find anything. I'll be glad for answers.

Comment: Is this (terribly formatted post) helpful? https://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/JDBC/9762-java-+-excel-data-+graph.html

Answer (score 1):

The trend line settings are not supported by the high level `XDDF` classes of `apache poi`. But using the underlying low level classes of `ooxml-schemas` it is possible.

You need the full `jar` of all the `ooxml-schemas`, which is `ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar` for `apache poi 4.x`  (lower versions for lower versions of `apache poi`).

Then, if you have a `XSSFChart chart` which is a bar chart and has at least two series, the following code adds a linear trend line to second series.

```
chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getBarChartArray(0).getSerArray(1)
 .addNewTrendline()
 .addNewTrendlineType()
 .setVal(org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.STTrendlineType.LINEAR);
```

If further trend line settings are needed, you need to know how to work using `ooxml-schemas` classes:

1. `Office Open XML` files like `*.xlsx` are simple `ZIP` archives. So one can unzip the `*.xlsx`  file and have a look into its raw `XML` content. For charts this is `/xl/charts/chart[n].xml`.
2. To get the needed changes, first create the chart and have a look at `/xl/charts/chart[n].xml`. Then do the needed changes using `Excel` and have a look at changed `/xl/charts/chart[n].xml`. Detect what exactly has changed. Now you know what needs to be done in `XML`.
3. Unfortunately there is no `API` documentation for `ooxml-schemas` public available. So to get one, you need download the [sources of ooxml-schemas](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/ooxml-schemas/1.4/). Then do `javadoc` from those. Now you have a `API` documentation for `ooxml-schemas`.
4. Now you now know what needs to be done in `XML`. And you have  a `API` documentation for `ooxml-schemas`. So you can look there how to do the `XML` programming. For trend-line changes start looking in `API` documentation of `org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTTrendline`.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: Your solution for adding a trend line works perfectly for me, but I would like to know if I can change the attributes of that line, like dashed, or dotted, or the color of the line?

Comment: @kpenrose: See supplements in my answer.